# ASP website only works by removing the namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working on a series of webpages using visual studio 2017. We are trying our best to not include any visual studio specific stuff, because we want to share this code with a couple of organisations that do not use visual studio.

Therefore, when I am deploying a web page to the server, I am having to do the following tasks:-

In my webforms, change first line of .aspx file from:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RCPR.aspx.cs" Inherits="recyclingcentrepermits.RCPR" %>
```

to

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile ="RCPR.aspx.cs" Inherits="RCPR" %>
```

I can understand why we need to change CodeBehind to CodeFile since we are deploying the C# code behind files are not the DLLs.

However, I do not have a clue why removing the namespace from the inherits clause there's anything. Can anybody explain this please?

The server has IIS 7.5.

The main reason I am asking this, is that I have just managed to implement an error trapping strategy, using the global class and custom error pages. This was awkward, as the main error I wanted to trap was:

> 401.2 access denied

However, by using the global class to convert this to a `303`, it now works, in visual studio anyway. However, it will not work on the server and I'm wondering whether this has anything to do with the changes I have explained above.

For further clarification, we are specifying the permitted users in the web.config, hence why other users will get access denied. We don't want instead of access denied, you do not have access to this page, please contact...

Thanks

Comment: "*ASP page change declaration from **[what]** to **[what]***"?

Comment: @Rafalon Questions sometimes include non-indented HTML-style tags, those don't get rendered. If it looks like some code is missing from the question, that's sometimes what happened. Feel free to edit the question in that case.

Comment: @mason yeah that's what I figured out, I was on my way through it when Joel Coehoorn edited it. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Whats getting deployed and how (ie web publish, ftp)?  What does your code behind class/namespace look like?  What error are you getting?

Comment: "using visual studio 2017"     "trying our best to not include any visual studio specific stuff"     Sorry, but aren't you causing your own problem here?